# Display a flash message on the same view after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a very basic app with 1 controller that has new and create methods and a form_for to create an entry in the database with the passed params.

When i hit submit the show view is rendered. Is there a way not to have the page redirect, so the view stays still the same with the form and a flash message get displayed at the top of the view?

I tried flash[:notice] and flash.now[:notice] but no luck.

this is my create controller

```
def create
@campaign = Campaign.new(params[:campaign])

respond_to do |format|
  if @campaign.save
    flash[:notice] = "Success"
    # format.html { redirect_to(@campaign, :notice => 'Successfully created.') }
    # format.xml  { render :xml => @campaign, :status => :created, :location => @campaign }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @campaign.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: So, don't redirect to `:show`. What's the question?

Comment: I edited the post and put my method there. It shouldnt redirect right?

Comment: you can check this... i have answered.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088027/issue-with-flash-messages-in-ruby-1-9-3-and-rails-3-2-2/10088301#10088301

Comment: when the create method is rendered i cant have the form rendered again.